# A word or phrase to describe documents that can expire

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I'm looking for word or phrase that describes documents or credentials that by definition have an expiry date.
Examples of such documents can be:

- Passports
- Certifications
- Licenses
- Credentials

Comment: There is a phrase: Documents with expiry dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can find no authority to support these, the terms *time-limited* and *time-restricted* seem to logically (and semantically) apply.

If you want a colloquial phrase, consider *good through (or thru)* and *good until* as adjectival phrases.

Answer (score 1):

- *Transient*-lasting only for a short time, (temporary)
- *Transitory*-not permanent
- *Temporary*

Comment: Thanks - are you suggesting 'Transient Documents'?